# Can two folders share the same localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am making an app that changes settings on my other app; they are both hosted on the same site just in different folders. Is there a way to make it so they both share the same localStorage?

Comment: So long as the origin (hostname, port, scheme) matches, they have the same storage.

Comment: localStorage is domain based. All pages with same domain share single localStorage

Comment: @jcubic if you could put that as an answer i will accept that as that was clear and i could understand it thank you!

Comment: Please note to dev this you'll probably be unable to test it on the `file:` protocol due to security restrictions (again related to same origin)

Comment: Thank you i will take this into account if i ever lose the password to my VPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

localStorage is domain based. All pages with same domain share single localStorage.

Also to share localStorage, both pages need to have the same port and protocol like https.

Comment: e.g. it uses the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Ok so i tried my normal things with localStorage and i put the files in a new folder and the localStorage didn't connect to the other folder? why would this be?

Comment: @JosephJamesShenton maybe you didn't save item in localstorage, did you use setItem and getItem methods?